# How to count number of LOG files in a specific directory using python

Tags: python

I have to make a function that takes a directory path or name and count number of LOG files inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def count_log_files(folder):

    return len([f for f in os.listdir(folder) if f.endswith('.LOG')])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
def log_count("/mydir"):
   count = 0
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mydir"):
       for file in files:
           if file.endswith(".LOG"):
                count += 1
    return count
```

This function will full fill the requirement. I always prefer to use os.walk because it is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

this would do

```py
import os
def log_file_count(path='.'):
    count = 0
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)) and file.lower().endswith('.log'):
            count += 1          
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use glob:

```
def count_file(directory: str, endwith: str) -> int:
    path_to_count = os.path.join(directory, f"*.{endwith}")    

    return len(glob.glob(path_to_count))

# Usage
counter = count_file(directory="/log", endwith="log")
print(counter)
```